# ngrok xampp and moodle, make localhost public with port forwarding error 303 see other

Tags: port, moodle, portforwarding, ngrok, http-status-code-303

i'm trying to make public my moodle site but without success.
First, i tried with the port forwarding from my router but it doesn't connect to the server, so i can imagine that there is a block from my router (i also free the port from the firewall in windows and internally the private_ip:8080 is working).
So i tried with ngrok but when i click the link from safari/chrome with my phone (on 4G) the connection gave me the error 303 see other and redirect me to localhost:8080 that of course my phone did not recognise.

[image]

Is there anyone that was able to exposed the moodle site with success?
Thank you

Comment: I am trying to do it as well but not yet success